# Как исправить баг интерфейса Sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-text, manjaro, xfce4

Прошу подсказать мне решение такого бага, установил я Sublime text 3 на ОС - Manjaro XFCE, и заметил след.

Текст в первой строке частично обрезан

[image]

Область выделения строки не центрирована, элементы подчеркивания скобок, тоже находятся немного ниже
[image]

При поиске такая же проблема, обрезаются буквы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Подчёркивание скобок это плагин
2. Пробовал менять темы, и цветовые схемы, не помогает (никаких изменений нет)
3. Пробовал менять шрифт Саблайма размеры, отступы, шрифт системы, тему системы - при этом перегружал саблайм (он не реагирует)

Судя по всему не правильно указан параметр центрирования, но где его найти, и можно ли вообще найти?
Гуглить пробовал, настройки sublime менял, но нужного параметра найти не удалось.
Буду признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в Xubuntu такого бага не возникает, но встречался с ним несколько раз в других программах, на других дистрибутивах. Практически всегда проблема решалась сменой системного моноширинного шрифта или его размеров. Попробуйте выставить такие же настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]